# How to catch the error, save it and then remove the error in foreach in R?

Tags: r, multithreading, try-catch, parallel.foreach

I am running a code and it is really important for me to catch the error and save it for later, but not include it in my final result of the foreach. I have used ***trycatch*** and even tried coercing an error using ***stop***. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
##options namely stop , remove or pass 
error_handle <- "remove"

cores <- round(detectCores()*percent)
cl<-makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
predict_load_all <- foreach(i=1:length(id),.export=func,.packages 
(.packages()),.errorhandling = error_handle) %dopar% {

possibleError <- tryCatch({
weather_cast <- data.frame(udata$date,j,coeff_i,predict(hour_fits[[j]], 
newdata=udata))
},error=function(e)return(paste0("The hour '",j, "'",
                                 " caused the error: '", e, "'")))

if(!exists("weather_cast")){
#possibleError <- data.frame('coeff_item' = coeff_i,'Error' = 
possibleError)
possibleError <- data.frame('Error' = possibleError)
write_csv(possibleError,file.path(path_predict,
'Error_weather_cast.csv'),append = T)
stop('error')
}
colnames(weather_cast)<- c("Date","Hour","coeff_item","Predicted_Load")

ifelse(j==1,predict_load <-weather_cast,predict_load <- 
rbind(predict_load,weather_cast))
predict_load <- spread(predict_load, Hour, Predicted_Load)
predict_load
}
```

I am running the foreach to output **predict_load_all**. **possibleError** is the error which needs to be saved, which is bound by a trycatch. This should save the object (satisfies exists condition) and then using **stop**, an error is induced which gets ignored by the **remove**(.errohandling object) and the loop in the foreach is skipped. This way, I get the error and a list without the errors.
This doesn't seem to be saving an error file.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't/shouldn't do something serial (like appending to a file)  with a parallelized loop. Write to separate files. Anyway, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Yes I understand, but I was try to catch the error by doing the above. Do you have any idea as to why my method above is not working and/or a solution to the above?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience (and I have a lot more "learning experiences" with parallel processing than actual success stories, unfortunately), this is not an easy task.  The best solution I found was to add `outfile = ''` to the `makeCluster` command.  For me, in a non-interactive mode, this caused (some of?) the error messages to get written to the output file instead of being discarded completely.

Comment: Can the **outfile**parameter be put with the **.errorhandling** parameter set to **remove**? Would it still catch the errors?